# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when using loop for creating JFormattedTextField

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception, jformattedtextfield

I want to create a few `JFormattedTextFields` but always get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` and I do not understand why.
The variable `globalZaehler2` is 51 and then I will get the exception. But my loop says it has to be < `field.length` (which is 51). So `globalZaehler2` can not be 51? Eclipse shows me the exception when I use `((JFormattedTextField)field[globalZaehler2]).selectAll();`

```
for (globalZaehler2 = 0; globalZaehler2 < field.length; globalZaehler2++) {
    if (field[globalZaehler2] instanceof JFormattedTextField) {
        ((JFormattedTextField)field[globalZaehler2]).addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
((JFormattedTextField)field[globalZaehler2]).selectAll();
                // do something with the text in the field
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You've provided a lot of code, but not a short but complete example - and we don't even know where it fails. Note that your code would be *much* simpler if you declared a local variable within your `if` statement: `final JFormattedTextField formattedField = (JFormattedTextField) field[globalZaehler2];`. You could then replace the 30+ occurrences of the cast with references to the local variable. The readability benefits would be *huge*.

Comment: Well it's still not a short but complete program. It looks like `globalZaehler2` shouldn't reach 51 in the loop if the length is 51. Ah... I see that this isn't a local variable though. That's the problem.

Comment: Yes if i use a local variabel here i get "Local variable globalZaehler2 defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final". But a final variable would not be useful, right?

Comment: Why are you using a field in a `for` loop anyway? That's almost *always* a bad idea. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can't tell terribly easily, but the name `globalZaehler2` makes it sound like this is a field, not a local variable. Using a field for an "index" variable in a `for` loop is almost *always* a bad idea... I can't remember the last time I wanted the state of an object to change like this within a loop.

That means by the time `actionPerformed` executes, you could have executed the loop various other times, with different lengths of fields. If you try to make it a local variable, however, you'll come up with a different problem, because you're referring to it within the anonymous inner class - which means it would need to be a *final* local variable... and that goes to the real problem here.

Basically, you want the code in `actionPerformed` to use the value of `globalZaehler2` *for that iteration of the loop*... but it's not executing during that iteration of the loop... it's executing when the action listener fires.

You *could* fix that by declaring a local variable within the loop:

```
for (globalZaehler2 = 0; globalZaehler2 < field.length; globalZaehler2++) {
    // In Java 8 you wouldn't need the final part
    final int copy = globalZaehler2;
    // Use copy instead of globalZaehler2 within actionPerformed
}
```

However, a far better solution would have two aspects:

- When you're *only* using the variable in the `for` loop as an index into an array, and you're traversing the whole array, use an enhanced for loop
- If you find yourself using a common subexpression multiple times in your code, extract that to a single expression

In your case, this would be:

```
// We don't know the type of field, so it's hard to guess the
// type here. Likewise I *would* use the name field, but that's the
// name of the array... it should probably be called fields, as it's
// naturally plural...
for (Object fooField : field) {
    if (fooField instanceof JFormattedTextField) {
        // Again, don't bother with final in Java 8
        final JFormattedTextField textField = (JFormattedTextField) fooField;
        textField.addActionListener(new ActionListener()) {
            @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                textField.selectAll();
                // etc
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Now you've *naturally* got a new local variable in the loop (`textField`) so it's fine for that to be effectively `final`, and to be used inside the `actionPerformed` method.

Comment: Looks way better and i do not get an exception. "field" ist a Component array, so i can replace "Object" with "Component"? Thanks for your help!